# Change style of the widgets in GTK#

Tags: mono, gtk, pygtk, gtk#, glade

Are there other methods for changing style of the widgets in GTK# like gtkrc themes? I already tried to use themes but not successfully. Pixbuf engine is the only engine which correctly rendered in my GTK# application, but when I trying to resize any widget, my UI is working slowly and freezes. So are there any other methods for changing style of the widgets in GTK# app without gtkrc?

Comment: Have you tried the possibility to change the style with css using a GtkCssProvider?

Comment: @elya5 no, but I can try. Is it support GTK# 2 which currently used in Xamarin studio? Has it the same opportunities as the gtkrc themes?

Comment: gtkrc is used to modify the appearance of all applications. The GtkCssProvider can be used by the programmer to only modify his application with css but I think it is only available in gtk+ 3.

Comment: @elya5 yes, but I found [this example of using css styling in GTK#](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/sample/GtkDemo/DemoCssBasics.cs). So how is it possible? I already tried this sample in GTK#, but I didn't find CssProvider class, how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must using **cairo** library to draw new widget.
below references is useful:

http://pygtk.org/articles/cairo-pygtk-widgets/cairo-pygtk-widgets.htm

http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/PyGTKCairoTutorial

http://manwhocodes.blogspot.com/2013/04/drawing-with-cairo-in-pygtk.html

http://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/

you can inherit from a gtk widget similar EventBox and change face of this and draw different face on firing different events.